# Python: Ordering Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I want to order some nested dictionaries to match the order of this list:

```
vehicle_type = ['Car', 'Bike', 'Bus']
```

This is currently what the nested dictionary looks like:

```
vehicles = {'2018': {'Bike': 2542, 'Bus': 37, 'Car': 33432}, '2012': {'Car': 68122, 'Bike': 164, 'Bus': 1653}, '2001': {'Car': 12127, 'Bus': 324, 'Bike': 4222}}
```

I have organised the outer keys which represent the years with:

```
ordered_dict = [(k, vehicles[k]) for k in sorted(list(vehicles.keys()))]
```

I'm just unsure on how I go through each year and organise their keys to the order of my vehicle_type list?
I'm probably being dumb

Comment: Given a dict `D` with the right keys but arbitrary order, `{key: D[key] for key in vehicle_type}` would produce a new dict in the right order.  Change to `{key: D.get(key) for ...` if some of the dicts might have missing keys (which this code would turn into explicit `None`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `dict comprehension` to re-order your keys based on your input list.

```
new_vehicles = {key: {d: v.get(d) for d in vehicle_type} for key, v in vehicles.items()}

new_vehicles
#{'2018': {'Car': 33432, 'Bike': 2542, 'Bus': 37}, '2012': {'Car': 68122, 'Bike': 164, 'Bus': 1653}, '2001': {'Car': 12127, 'Bike': 4222, 'Bus': 324}}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Was so close by the methods I was trying haha

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dict like

```py
{'Bike': {'2001', 164, '2012', 4222, '2018', 2542}, 'Bus': {'2001', 324, 37, 1653, '2012', '2018'}, 'Car': {'2001', 33432, '2012', 68122, '2018', 12127}}
```

you should write something like

```py
vehicles_by_type = {}
for year, vehicle_in_year in vehicles.items():
    for vehicle_type, x in vehicle_in_year.items():
        if not vehicle_type in vehicles_by_type:
            vehicles_by_type[vehicle_type] = {}
        vehicles_by_type[vehicle_type].update({year, x})
```